# Updating to JQuery 3.6.0, and Jquery UI has JQMigrate errors

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

We are being required to update to JQuery 3.6.0 to fix some of the security issues found in previous versions.  As part of that, I am trying to upgrade JQuery UI to the version that has been updated after 1.12.1 to handle the JQMigrate errors that are occurring within it.

Is there any way to download a newer version, or get a one combined with all the files correctly combined?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version is jQuery UI 1.12.1.
You can review this here:

https://code.jquery.com/

**jQuery UI**

Showing the latest stable release for the current and legacy release families. See all versions of jQuery UI.

jQuery UI 1.12

- jQuery UI 1.12.1 - [uncompressed](https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js), [minified](https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js)

[**Draggable & Sortable Demo Test**](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable)

```js
$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable({
    revert: true
  });
  $("#draggable").draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#sortable",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $("ul, li").disableSelection();
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

li {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="draggable" class="ui-state-highlight">Drag me down</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @ChadYost you may also want to read through https://blog.jquery.com/2021/03/02/jquery-3-6-0-released/

Comment: Again, NOT helpful.  I read that.  It doesn't say anything about JQuery UI, which has the code that has been deprecated by JQuery itself.

We are upgrading from JQuery 3.4.1, so some of the deprecated methods happened in 3.5.  Still, the changes were made to the JQuery UI Git repository, just want to know how to get the JQUERY UI changes.